# Point to same router-outlet from two different components

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have Component1, and Component2.

`<router-outlet>` is in Component1 Template.

Component1

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
   <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/link1']">Link1</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now in Component2, I would also have routerLinks, but no router-outlet.

Component2

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
   <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/link2']">Link2</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like that `[routerLink]` from Component2 points to `<router-outlet>` in Component1

So how could I attach routerLinks to specific router-outlets? I tried using router naming, but it didn't workout.

Folder Structure:

```
src/app/components
--- Component1
    --- component1.component.html
--- Component2
    --- component2.component.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do just do it by using `../` in `routerLink` URL, eventually that will point to parent `router-outlet`(behind the scenes it goes one URL fragment back).

```
[routerLink]="['../link2']"
```

Comment: I've edited my question with a folder structure. The problem with ../ is that it doesn't go in my Component2 folder. So I would have to do something like ../Component2/link2 ? But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @masterfan I'm not talking about folder structure, I was talking about URL fragments..

Comment: But it still doesn't find parent router-outlet. If I remove router-outlet from Component2 (I don't want it there, since I want to link it to router-outlet in Component1) I get: "Cannot find primary outlet to load..."